# cannot convert from byte to string (VB.Net to C#)

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a code written in VB.net and translated it to C# (through some site). The code is not complicated so most of the translation turned out fine with no problems what so ever.
One problem, though, is really causing me a headache and while it is referenced in many websites (including this one), I still can't get it to run.
I have a function in VB.Net decalred as:

```
Public Shared Function UTF8HexToByte(ByVal str As String) As Byte
```

and the translator altered it to:

```
public static byte UTF8HexToByte(string str)
```

Later on, in my C# code, I'm calling this function:

```
   for (int i = 0; i <= Key1.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                Key1[i] = 16 * UTF8HexToByte(TempKey1[2 * i]) + UTF8HexToByte(TempKey1[2 * i + 1]);

            }
```

but what is working in VB.net does not work here. I'm getting this error:

Error   7   The best overloaded method match for 'maker.Resources.makeC.UTF8HexToByte(string)' has some invalid arguments

Error   8   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'byte' to 'string'

Now, I guess the problem is that `UTF8HexToByte` is receiving a string and returning a byte, whereas I give it a byte `TempKey1` and not a string.
But it does work at the VB.Net code, so I'm confused... here's the code for VB.Net:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To Key1.Length - 1
        Key1(i) = 16 * UTF8HexToByte(TempKey1(2 * i)) + UTF8HexToByte(TempKey1(2 * i + 1))
    Next
```

TempKey is a byte[], Key1 is a byte[].

Any help will do. I'm really stuck on this one.

Comment: Would `char(TempKey1)` work? Otherwise, are you sure the error is there? If `Key1` is a byte, as you say, I'd expect an error on `Key1.Length`. Or did you mean "is an array of bytes"?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.metadata.w3cxsd2001.soaphexbinary(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Try explicitly converting the byte to a string; i.e. UTF8HexToByte(TempKey1[2 * i].ToString())

Comment: I guess it's a matter of implicit casting happening in VB.NET. C# is more type safe and prevents you to call such an interface using mistyped arguments warning you at compile time. You may need to eventually explicitely cast doing this (string)argument. Anyway the UTF8HexToByte has a very misleading signature and probably the whole strategy should be refactored.

Comment: @MrLister array of bytes. Sorry, I'll edit the q.

Answer (score 0):

Method signature tells you that it is expecting string.   `'maker.Resources.makeC.UTF8HexToByte(string)' has some invalid arguments`
Change

```
Key1[i] = 16 * UTF8HexToByte(TempKey1[2 * i]) + UTF8HexToByte(TempKey1[2 * i + 1]);
```

to

```
Key1[i] = 16 * UTF8HexToByte(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(new []{TempKey1[2 * i]})) + UTF8HexToByte(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(new []{TempKey1[2 * i + 1]}));
```

Comment: I did it, and now getting this message:  Error 7 Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'byte'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?). I guess it is because i is an integer? Am I right?

Comment: Updated answer, and yes you might need to cast.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not great with VB.NET, but a quick bit of test code shows that it's quite happy with me passing a `byte` into a function that expects `string`. This is not something C# is going to be happy with at all, so you've got no choice but to write some code which does the conversion.

To get that and keep the semantics of your original code, you need to figure out what VB.NET does to convert from `byte` to `string` and duplicate it.

It is not at all improbable that this is just a call to the `byte`'s `ToString()` method, so

```
Key1[i] = 16 * UTF8HexToByte(TempKey1[2 * i].ToString()) + UTF8HexToByte(TempKey1[2 * i + 1].ToString());
```

One thing you will find in C# is that it's a lot stricter about types and type conversions, forcing you to think about how data changes from one format to another.

Answer (score 0):

There is no implicit or automatic conversion between `byte` and `string` in C#. Your best bet is to get a `string` via `string.Format`:

```
string.Format("{0}", yourByte)
```

As @Mr Lister noted, `string.Format` will return a string with the numerical value of the byte. If you need to interpret it as an ASCII character, then just cast it to `char`:

```
(char)yourByte
```

Comment: That will result in strings like "122" instead of the desired "z".

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get that the character was needed. In that case, casting to char is enough: `(char)yourByte`.